# Maximum characters that can be stuffed into raw_input() in Python

Tags: python, raw-input

For an InterviewStreet challenge, we have to be able to accomodate for a 10,000 character String input from the keyboard, but when I copy/paste a 10k long word into my local testing, it cuts off at a thousand or so.

What's the official limit in Python? And is there a way to change this?

Thanks guys

Here's the challenge by-the-by:

http://www.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/solve/view/4e1491425cf10/4edb8abd7cacd

Comment: there is no such limit. there might be a stray newline in your pasted input.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357007/python-raw-input-limit-with-mac-os-x-terminal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure of the fact that your *10k* long word doesn't contain newlines?

---

> **[raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input)([prompt])**
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.
>
> ...
>
> If the [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#module-readline) module was loaded, then raw_input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

There is no maximum limit (in python) of the buffer returned by `raw_input`, and as I tested some big length of input to *stdin* I could not reproduce your result. I tried to search the web for information regarding this but came up with nothing that would help me answer your question.

**my tests**

```
  :/tmp% python -c 'print "A"*1000000' | python -c 'print len (raw_input ())';
  1000000
  :/tmp% python -c 'print "A"*210012300' | python -c 'print len (raw_input ())';
  210012300
  :/tmp% python -c 'print "A"*100+"\n"+"B"*100' | python -c 'print len (raw_input ())'; 
  100
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the excellent, simple demonstration.  Nice work.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same experience, and found python limits the length of input to `raw_input` if you do not import the `readline` module. Once I imported the `readline` module, it lifted the limit (or at least raised it significantly enough to where the text I was using worked just fine). This was on my Mac with Python `2.7.15`. Additionally, it’s been confirmed working on at least `3.9.5`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million! This worked for me as well (Python 2.7.17, Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Worked for me on Python 3.9.5, macOS.

Comment: Thanks @Dae—I updated the answer to note that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is part of the challenges. The [faq](http://www.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/faq/view#stdio) suggest raw_input() might not be the optimal approach:

> The most common (possibly naive) methods are listed below. (...)

There are indeed Python standard modules helping to handle system input/output.