# 1024 character input length limit when dragging and dropping files onto Terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I'm writing a Python script to run in the Terminal on OSX for batch-tagging music files. Once I launch the program, I want to be able to drag and drop batches of directories onto the Terminal, and for the program to processes all the files in the directories.

What I have works fine… so long as I don't drop too may folders onto the Terminal when asked for input. If I drop too many folders on, it gets stuck and I have to terminate. It looks like there's some kind of limit on the length of input to 1024 characters in this circumstance. I've tested it and even just typing/copypasting (rather than dragging/dropping), I cannot input more than 1024 characters.

What is mysterious to me is that if I simply go into Terminal and start up Python there, typing `input()` lets me drag and drop an unlimited number of folders. I can save the input into a string and manipulate it however I want.

When I launch my program in Terminal, though, the `input()` line no longer works in the same way and has the 1024 character limit.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I might be able to run the script in Terminal while being able to drop on as many folders as I want?

Comment: I found a fix here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357007/python-raw-input-limit-with-mac-os-x-terminal

Importing the `readline` module lifts the limit.

I do not know why, but this works for my purposes.

If someone can explain the reason why, would be interesting.

Comment: "Importing the readline module lifts the limit".. you just saved me a lot of time/headaches... thanks